# Reducing precision of GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, precision

We have a large number of GeoJSON shapes that are stored in a datastore.
Currently, the GeoJSON coordinates are being stored with 15 decimals, which is accurate up to picometers.
We don't need that kind of precision, so we'd like to lower it to 7 digits in order to save some storage.

However, the data comes from external sources so we tried reducing the precision by simply omitting the last 8 digits. However, this cause some shapes to become invalid due to duplicate points. When we remove the duplicate points, the shapes can become invalid.

Is there a general process that should be followed when reducing the precision?

Comment: What is your datastore? - postgis can do ST_QuantizeCoordinates https://postgis.net/docs/ST_QuantizeCoordinates.html#

Comment: The data store is elasticsearch